# query log in Wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, logging

How to get a log of MySQL query by means of Wordpress?
I need queries for a certain period, for example day.
Since the site on a shared hosting, enabling the slow query log is not possible.

I know how to get the list of queries for generation of a particular page.
But I need to find out what creates a load on the server database.

Comment: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-queries/

Comment: Can this plugin collect statistics for some period?